# how do i make a function that will accept a string and return the second character from the string?

Tags: java

For example if the function is given the string "ABCD" the function should return the letter B. This is code i've written so far but i'm getting a few errors which i've been trying to fix for three hours now!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Stringg {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.print("Please enter a string: "); 
    mystring = Scanner.nextLine();
    public static char getSecondChar(String myString) { 
    return myString.charAt(1); 
    }
    System.out.println("The second character is " + getSecondChar  (myString));
```

Comment: *Always* post errors you're receiving. What makes you think you can define a method in main like that?

Comment: @Kayaman agreed!!! This is a duplicate question.

Comment: You're trying to declare one method inside another. Don't do that, basically.

Comment: and you need to define the variable `mystring` as `String` because it has no type yet.

Comment: There are many methods of `String` class you can use. Like `charAt` or `substring()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Do not create your function inside the main method. You will only need to call the function inside the main method to work.

```
public class Stringg {

    public static char getSecondChar(String myString) { 
        return myString.charAt(1); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a string: "); 
        String mystring = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("The second character is " + getSecondChar(mystring));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       public class SecondChar {
        public static char secondChar(String str){
            char[] charArray=str.toCharArray();
                if(charArray.length<=1)
            {
                 System.out.println("String does not have 2nd character!");
                 return 0;
            }
            return charArray[1];
        }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        String str="ABCD";
        System.out.println(secondChar(str));
    }
    }
```

Comment: What if input string contains only one character ?

Comment: the ques didnt asked abt only 1 char string. But in that case we can put an if condition. I have updated ans accordingly. :)

Comment: There is no need of converting string into char array, you can simply use String's charAt() for returning second character.

Comment: It can be done in multiple ways though! I chose this :)

Answer (score 0):

In java, writing a function inside a function doesn't mean anything. You need to write functions in different scopes.